# When using Itext or itextsharp, how do determine the length to set a digital cert buffer length?

Tags: c#, certificate, itext, digital-signature

I am working with itextsharp (but this question is probably applies to itext also) and I am adding digital signatures to PDFs. I have done reading and I understand that the length of a digital signature will vary based on LTV, and a hole host of other factors, so you typically will allocate an overly large buffer to hold the certificate information when you add the signature to a document to insure that it will have sufficient space.

The thing that is puzzling to me is I see examples all over the net where a sig stamper is set up like this:

```
Dictionary<PdfName, int> exc = new Dictionary<PdfName, int>();
exc.Add(PdfName.CONTENTS, BUFFER_SIZE * 2 + 2);
sap.PreClose(exc);
```

and then later is zeroed out

```
byte[] signature_buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

int index = 0;
while (index < signature_buffer.Length)
signature_buffer[index++] = 0x20;

PdfDictionary dic2 = new PdfDictionary();
dic2.Put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(signature_buffer).SetHexWriting(true));
```

Why do we create the initial dictionary entry with a buffer length * 2 + 2? Why isn't it the same size as the one used by the PdfDictionary? Is a case where sloppy code has just been copied all over the place, or is there a deeper reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do we create the initial dictionary entry with a buffer length * 2 + 2?

This is explained in the method comment of `PdfSignatureAppearance.preClose` in iText (it likely is identical in iTextSharp):

```
/**
 * This is the first method to be called when using external signatures. The general sequence is:
 * preClose(), getDocumentBytes() and close().
 * <p>
 * If calling preClose() <B>dont't</B> call PdfStamper.close().
 * <p>
 * <CODE>exclusionSizes</CODE> must contain at least
 * the <CODE>PdfName.CONTENTS</CODE> key with the size that it will take in the
 * document. Note that due to the hex string coding this size should be
 * byte_size*2+2.
 * @param exclusionSizes a <CODE>HashMap</CODE> with names and sizes to be excluded in the signature
 * calculation. The key is a <CODE>PdfName</CODE> and the value an
 * <CODE>Integer</CODE>. At least the <CODE>PdfName.CONTENTS</CODE> must be present
 * @throws IOException on error
 * @throws DocumentException on error
 */
public void preClose(HashMap<PdfName, Integer> exclusionSizes) throws IOException, DocumentException
```

As explained here, **due to the hex string coding this size should be byte_size*2+2** because *the size that* the signature container *will take in the document* is

- twice the length in bytes (due to hex encoding)
- plus 2 (for the opening and closing angled brackets enclosing hex encoded strings in PDF).

Comment: Ah, that totally makes sense. Thanks for the info, I wanted to make sure that I was doing this correctly and not perpetuating a bad hack.